# osmupdate Error: Merging of changefiles failed

Tags: openstreetmap

I use the tool `osmupdate` to update the pbf file I get from http://download.gisgraphy.com/openstreetmap/pbf/ (without a pbf suffix by default).

At first merging change files can be finished smoothly but soon it got a error like this:

```
Killed
osmupdate Error: Merging of changefiles failed: 
osmconvert --merge-versions  "osmupdate_temp/temp.d000001399.osc.gz" 
"osmupdate_temp/temp.d000001400.osc.gz" 
"osmupdate_temp/temp.d000001401.osc.gz" 
"osmupdate_temp/temp.d000001402.osc.gz" 
"osmupdate_temp/temp.d000001403.osc.gz" 
"osmupdate_temp/temp.h000033666.osc.gz"  
"osmupdate_temp/temp.h000033667.osc.gz" "osmupdate_temp/temp.8" 
-- timestamp=2016-07-16T08:07:02Z --out-o5c >"osmupdate_temp/temp.9"
```

I have found that the problem lies in shortage of memory since the temp data is much bigger than the original data. Since I only need the updated nodes, how can I get the updated nodes information only?

Comment: For me, I am not sure whether the problem lies in memory shortage.

Comment: "Killed" sounds strange. Did you check `dmesg` for out of memory messages?

Comment: @scai Yeah you are right, it is a memory problem. Though the target update file is about 20MB, each temp file is about 600MB.